# Angular application gets suspended when user switches to another tab of browser - How to prevent it?

Tags: angular, angular10

I am developing a Angular Application in which I found that if my data is loading on the table in application & in between I switch to another tab of browser, the application stops loading content & resumes back only when I come back to my application. This happens for everything, example I am downloading a file by clicking on button to fetch data from another microservice in my application & switch to another tab, the downloading/ call to the microservice stops & resumes once I come back.

I want to prevent this from happening. As, it is consuming lot of time of users to wait for loading of data/ downloading to complete. I am using GCP(Google cloud platform for various cases in my application example firestore).

Any suggestions or recommendations are welcomed!!!

Comment: Its a feature of browsers to reduce memory/CPU consumption for tabs that aren't visible. I would recommend a web worker to offload the processing.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I will surely try web worker.